# Automatically assign unique random ids for instances of a struct

Tags: rust, identifier

Completely new rustacean. Suppose I have this piece of code:

```rust
use random_string;

struct IDManager {
    length: usize,
    charset: String,
    registered_ids: Vec<String>,
}

impl IDManager {
    fn generate(&mut self) -> &String {
        loop {
            let id = random_string::generate(
                self.length, 
                &self.charset
            );
            if !self.registered_ids.contains(&id) {
                self.registered_ids.push(id);
                return self.registered_ids.last().unwrap();
            }
        }
    }
}

impl Default for IDManager{
    fn default() -> Self {
        IDManager { 
            length: 32, 
            registered_ids: vec![],
            charset: [
                "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
                "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
                "0123456789",
            ].concat(), 
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person<'a> {
    id: &'a String,
    name: String,
    age: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut person_id_manager: IDManager = Default::default();
    let person = Person {
        id: person_id_manager.generate(),
        name: "Bob".to_string(),
        age: 32,
    };
    println! ("{:?}", person)    
}
```

The problem with this code is that the `person_id_manager` is not really tied to the `struct Person`. Users are still free to give whatever `id` they want to the `Person` which is not what we want. Instead, ideally, we want to yield no control to the users how the `id` of a `Person` is generated, better if it is completely invisible.

I thought of adding a `IDManager` "static attribute" to the "class" of `Person`, which `Person` is obviously not because it is a `struct`. What is the idiomatic way to do this in Rust?

Answer (score 1):

Usually in Rust, you limit access to fields by not making them public. In your example, the user of `Person` is only able to access the private fields because you've put everything in one module.

It's hard to say exactly what is idiomatic here, because it looks like a slightly unusual requirement and the "best" approach will depend on what you *really* are trying to achieve. However, it is idiomatic in Rust to use `new` method to control how objects are constructed.

Since the fields are all private, if you provide a public `new` method, this will be the only way that `Person` can be constructed outside of the module, so you can control exactly how this is done.

At this point you could make use of a shared `static` instance of `IdManager`, but since you asked about an idiomatic approach and global variables are not typically recommended in any language, let's do something different:

```
impl<'a> Person<'a> {
    pub fn new(id_manager: &'a mut IdManager, name: String, age: u32) -> Self {
        Person {
            name,
            age,
            id: id_manager.generate()
        } 
    }
}
```

This requires users of the `Person` struct to have access to an `IdManager` in order to create one.

Comment: But with this, still the user has to pass an id_manager instance. Is there way to have a predefined id_manager from the developer side that cannot be altered by the user?

Comment: Yes, you can do that too.